# Inserir dados no grafico

Tags: javascript, html, chartjs

Tenho o seguinte código:

```js
window.onload = function () {
 var chart = new CanvasJS.Chart("chartContainer",
 {
  title:{
   text: "Desktop Search Engine Market Share, Dec-2012"
  },
                animationEnabled: true,
  legend:{
   verticalAlign: "center",
   horizontalAlign: "left",
   fontSize: 20,
   fontFamily: "Helvetica"        
  },
  theme: "theme2",
  data: [
  {        
   type: "pie",       
   indexLabelFontFamily: "Garamond",       
   indexLabelFontSize: 20,
   indexLabel: "{label} {y}%",
   startAngle:-20,      
   showInLegend: true,
   toolTipContent:"{legendText} {y}%",
   dataPoints: [
    {  y: 83.24, legendText:"Google", label: "Google" },
    {  y: 8.16, legendText:"Yahoo!", label: "Yahoo!" },
    {  y: 4.67, legendText:"Bing", label: "Bing" },
    {  y: 1.67, legendText:"Baidu" , label: "Baidu"},       
    {  y: 0.98, legendText:"Others" , label: "Others"}
   ]
  }
  ]
 });
 chart.render();
}
```

```html
<script src="https://canvasjs.com/assets/script/canvasjs.min.js"></script>
<!DOCTYPE HTML>




<body>
<div id="chartContainer" style="height: 300px; width: 100%;"></div>
```

Gostaria de inserir meu proprio valor no gráfico.
O retorno do meu php é assim:

```
[
  {
    "y": 83.24,
    "legendText": "Google",
    "label": "Google"
  },
  {
    "y": 8.16,
    "legendText": "Yahoo!",
    "label": "Yahoo!"
  },
  {
    "y": 4.67,
    "legendText": "Bing",
    "label": "Bing"
  },
  {
    "y": 1.67,
    "legendText": "Baidu",
    "label": "Baidu"
  },
  {
    "y": 0.98,
    "legendText": "Others",
    "label": "Others"
  }
]
```

Estou tentando colocar esse valor no lugar e não consigo:

Já tentei assim:

```
var dados = [];  
  $.ajax({
     url : 'file.php',
     type : 'post',
     dataType : 'json',
     data :{
        acao  : 'a' 
      }
      ,success : function( data ){

         $.each( data, function( i, j ){
            dados.push( j )
         } ); 

      }
  });
```

Eu substituir os dados pelo meu e nada.

Answer (score 0):

Você tem dois modos de fazer isso:

Construido uma array no PHP e incorpora-la ao JS, ou construir um string no formato, e printar em cima do JS, na minha opnião, a primeira é melhor, a segunda é mais fácil.

dataPoints nada mais é do que a array da series, no caso, vocẽ ja tem um array, acho mais fácil transformá-lo em um string, e printar sobre o JS.

Construindo a string:

```
<?php
$arr = [
    1 => [
    "y" => 83.24,
    "legendText" => "Google",
    "label" => "Google"
  ],
  2 => [
    "y" => 8.16,
    "legendText" => "Yahoo!",
    "label" => "Yahoo!"
  ],
  3 =>
  [
    "y"=> 4.67,
    "legendText"=> "Bing",
    "label"=> "Bing"
  ],
  4 =>
  [ "y"=> 1.67,
    "legendText"=> "Baidu",
    "label"=> "Baidu"
  ],
  5=>
  [
    "y" => 0.98,
    "legendText" => "Others",
    "label" => "Others"
  ]
];


$count = count($arr);
$str = '[';
$limit = 1;
foreach($arr as $row){
    $str .= '{';
    $str .= '"y":'.$row['y'].',';
    $str .= '"legentText":"'.$row['legendText'].'",';
    $str .= '"label":"'.$row['label'].'"';

    if($limit < $count){
        $str .= '},';   
    }else{
        $str .= '}';
    }
    $limit += 1;
}
$str .= ']';

echo $str;
```

`$str` responde isso:

```
[{"y":83.24,"legentText":"Google","label":"Google"},{"y":8.16,"legentText":"Yahoo!","label":"Yahoo!"},{"y":4.67,"legentText":"Bing","label":"Bing"},{"y":1.67,"legentText":"Baidu","label":"Baidu"},{"y":0.98,"legentText":"Others","label":"Others"}]
```

Basta printar essa string dentro de dataPoints, e seu gráfico foi construido através dessa array.

Obs: Respondi desse modo com string pois não sei usar essa api de gráficos, sempre uso a fusionCharts por ter uma classe que permite renderizar direto com PHP.

Comment: Tens um tutorial de como usar o fusionCharts ?

Comment: é a mesma coisa praticamente, a unica diferença, é que no lugar de instanciar um JS, você instancia um classe php, e passa um json bem parecido com esse, http://www.fusioncharts.com/php-charts/ da uma olhada aqui.